# Haml/Twig in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, syntax, haml, twig

I'm learning Symfony 2 and I decided to learn ow to implement Haml on my Twig templates.
It works well, but I have a question.

It is possible to write :

```
%span = article.author
```

It is NOT possible to write :

```
%span by = article.author
```

However, it is possible to write alternatively :

```
%span by #{ article.author }
```

I like the "= variable" syntax, and I don't like the idea of using two different syntaxes on a single template for the same action (display a variable value) on various lines in my template. And sorry for my bad english. :p

Is there any way to write something like

```
%span by = article.author
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to separate it into two lines:

```
%span
  by
  = article.author
```

HAML recognizes `=` only at line beginnings (it would be quite bothersome having to escape equation signs, although they are probably not used often.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with HAML, but printing/echoing in twig is with the `{{ ... }}` delimiters, so wouldn't you need

```
%span = {{ article.author }}
```

??

Comment: Not with HAML ! :) Here #{...} is used for string interpolation, so I don't know if there is a solution to my "issue", because I think the "= variable" syntax is used to display a value and only that on the same line.

Comment: Well, that depends on when the HAML is parsed - before or after Twig? If you've set up you view layer so that the HAML is parsed first, then I'd argue that you're "doing it wrong" since Twig should generate valid HAML, and then let the HAML generate valid HTML.

Comment: I don't know. But I got a clear and concise response somewhere else : No, you can't. So I guess my question can be closed.